# Acronyms containing acronyms expand incorrectly

Tags: glossaries

I have the following MWE where the long version of an acronym contains other acronyms:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}

\makenoidxglossaries

\newacronym{hdl}  {HDL}  {hardware description language}
\newacronym{vhdl} {VHDL} {\gls{vhsic} \gls{hdl}}
\newacronym{vhsic}{VHSIC}{very high speed integrated circuit}

\setacronymstyle{long-short}% commenting this line eliminates the problem

\begin{document}
    \section{MWE}
    Something weird happens when I say \gls{vhdl}.

    It also happens in case the nested acronyms are already expanded: \glsreset{vhdl}\gls{vhdl}.

    But not in this case: \gls{vhdl}.
\end{document}
```

This is the result:

> Something weird happens when I say very high speed integrated circuit (VHSIC) hardware description language (HDL) (HDL).
>
> It also happens in case the nested acronyms are already expanded: VHSIC HDL (HDL).
>
> But not in this case: VHDL.

The problem goes away if I don't explicitly specify `long-short` as the acronym style. But why does it occur in the first place?

Comment: I think, this is explained (somehow) on page 123 of the current `glossaries-user` manual, see the text below the `\Genplacrfullformat` description

Comment: Explained in more detail in [the glossaries-extra manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries-extra/glossaries-extra-manual.html#sec:nested). Also, you must set the acronym style before you define them.